# /me/home doesn't return all the posts

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I've noticed that me/home in the Graph API doesn't return posts by certain users. I've tried this in my app as well as just using Graph Explorer. It returns most posts, consistently fails to include posts by certain friends. I don't think this is a caching issue, because I've tried over a period of one day with same results. It's not random either. It's the same handful of posts that are always missing.

I checked the posts in question and don't see anything special. And it's happening with newer posts also.

Do I need to add any special parameters to my request ?

Comment: Those friends postings that are being excluded, can you find them in the FQL Stream for the user?

Answer (score 0):

Users, in their Facebook privacy preferences, can configure what data 3rd party applications can see about themselves.

What you are seeing is that certain users have made their activities not viewable to your application.